# Python packages embedded in .zip add-on and relative paths

Tags: python, add-on, path

I am developing an add-on, which needs few Python packages. I have been trying to make the installation of python packages easier for other users. I was thinking about including these Python packages into the .zip file of the add-on. Would this approach work? Can I use relative paths to call these python packages?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. Have you tried to do it ?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. But I guess there is something wrong in how I call the packages then. Basically I have my my_addon.zip with three files (__init__.py, operators.py and panels.py) and a folder (python package - mako). I am using the mako package in the operators.py file. I tried to use "from .mako.template import Template" but it did not work.

Comment: You can also directly install packages in the local python environment with pip

Comment: Can I avoid using pip? It would be nice if users just need to download the .zip file and install it in Blender